# How to show datatable in DXChart

Tags: c#, charts, devextreme

I'm currently working with a large dataset and dxcharts. 
Showing the data labels has become a problem caused by the quantity of information and the size of the chart. I resolved part of the problem thanks to the zoom tool of dxchart but it would like to show the values of the series as a data table under the x axis the same way a Excel chart can do it.
After reading all the documentation on devexpress, I cant find a way for the data table to show or even know if its possible.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such functionality in DevExtreme charts. I think tooltip or crosshair cursor might help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the same datasource to a dxdatagrid as a second widget. Without knowing your exact data structure, this could be easy or hard.

I found this in the devexpress knowledgebase.
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T440661/datasource-share-it-between-multiple-widgets